# What is the problem of this code in c++? I've to work with c-string

Tags: c++, c-strings

I have created an array of c-string. this code takes input for three strings and then displays it on the console.
but unfortunately, the input is fine but the output display doesn't working.

```
int main()
{
    char *str[20];
    std::cout << "Enter values to strings: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nstr" << i<<": ";
        std::cin >> str[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n\nouput:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nstr" << i<<":";
        std::cout << str[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str` is an array of 20 uninitialized pointers. Using those pointers for anything is undefined. You need to create space for your strings. (SInce you "have to" work with C strings, you should know about methods for doing this already.)

Comment: the code you posted cannot compile. Please post a [mcve] including input, output and expected output

Comment: What do you need to do with C string that cannot be done using `std::string` and `c_str()` method ?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, using uninitialized pointers is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). If you need to work with C-strings (i.e. you cannot use `std::string`, which I would normally recommend), just allocate the memory for your C-string with `operator new`. One possible approach is to define some constant max length of the expected input string, read input to the buffer, then allocate necessary memory and copy the data to the newly allocated space:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

constexpr int MAX_STR_LEN = 255;

int main()
{
    char *str[20];
    char buff[MAX_STR_LEN];  // going to read strings here and copy them to `str` array
    std::memset(buff, 0, MAX_STR_LEN);  // fill the buffer with zeroes
    std::cout << "Enter values to strings: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nstr" << i<<": ";
        std::cin >> buff;
        str[i] = new char[std::strlen(buff)+1];  // +1 for terminating null
        std::memcpy(str[i], buff, std::strlen(buff));
        str[i][std::strlen(buff)] = 0;  // last character should be null
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n\nouput:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nstr" << i<<":";
        std::cout << str[i];
        delete[] str[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this example is good for exercise purpose only, normally C++ developer would use `std::vector<std::string>` to keep dynamic array of strings.

Comment: You can generally still create `std::string` even if you have to send them to a C library as a C string. `std::string` internally have to store the string as a C string (since C++11) for that purpose and provides the `c_str()` method to access this internal string as a `char *`. We should still prefer `std::string` in C++ code and follow what you'd normally recommend.

Comment: @NicolasDusart `std::string` has had `c_str()` for C compatibility long before C++11. It is only the *internal storage* that was standardized in C++11, following practices that most implementations had already been using.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, that's what I meant. Maybe the phrasing was not accurate enough. But the internal storage requirement enforce the compatibility. We can now send a non-const `char *` intended to be filled up by a C library (given the fact that we need to `resize()` the `std::string` afterwards to match the new internal length) which was not standardized before C++11. Since C++11, I don't see any use case where we cannot use a `std::string` in C++ side.